# Amazon Revert the master password of RDS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have accidentally changed the RDS master password on Amazon. I don't have putty access to files and now the application is not working because db connection is lost. Is there a way that I can revert my changes or any other way to access the code and change the db password there? I do have console access of Amazon but lost the PEM file of currently running instance.

**EDIT**
Because of the MAster password change I am getting this error on my application

```
mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'arianadbmyadmin'@'172.31.5.67' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: so why don't you change the password back on RDS? Don't you remember it?

Comment: @DiegoVelezi didn't set the password initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 steps are needed :

- Generate AMI from the current EC2.
- Launch new instance from that AMI ( specify new pem,.. so on)
- Terminate the old EC2.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Everything will be changed in this way. All the routes and ips etc. can i access the code without having a pem file?

Comment: My solution is to let you be able to access your code inside an EC2 and update whatever you want. Your issue ( if I understood well ) is about EC2 access.